# Show that these vectors are linearly independent almost surely

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, stochastic-matrices

So I'm doing research in control theory and I have been stuck with this problem for a while. Let me explain my issue, then my proposal, and finally my concrete question.

**Problem:** I have $m<n$ real $n\times n$ positive definite matrices $P_1,\dotsc,P_m$. These define ellipsoids $E_i=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mathrel:x^TP_ix=1\}$. I'm interested in the points that lie in the intersection of all these ellipsoids (let's call it $E\mathrel{:=}\bigcap_{i=1}^mE_i$ for short). However, there are points which are troublesome (let's called them non regular). A point $x$ is non regular if

- $x\in E$.
- The vectors $\{P_1x,\dotsc,P_mx\}$ are linearly dependent.

So, matrices $P_1,\dotsc,P_m$ that induce non regular points are problematic in my case. And ideally I would want to show that these matrices can be perturbed a little such that these non regular points disappear.

**Proposal:** I want to show that given $P_1,\dotsc,P_m$, if you substitute $P_i\leftarrow P_i+\varepsilon_i$ with $\varepsilon_i$ a random matrix with elements uniformly distributed in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ (or some other distribution if desired),  the probability of a point $x\in E$ to be nonregular is 0. Or equivalently that $x$ is "regular" almost surely for any $\epsilon>0$.

Now, for $\{P_1x,\dotsc,P_mx\}$ to be linearly independent (with $P_i$ taking into account the random matrices $\varepsilon_i$) we require the existence of coefficients $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_m$ such that the matrix $H=\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i P_i$ is singular. Thus, non regular points $x$ must lie in the intersection of $E$ and the kernel of $H$. Moreover, since $x^THx=0$ and $x^TP_ix=1$, thus $\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i=0$. Existence of coefficients $\alpha_i$ with these characteristics (with $\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i=0$ and $H$ singular) are guaranteed as described in the answer of this other question of mine [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373664/necessary-conditions-for-existence-of-linear-combination-of-these-matrices-to-be), so my hope to show that $H$ is non-singular almost surely vanished. But I can still try to show that the probability $P(\text{$\{x\in E\}$ and $\{x\in\operatorname{ker} H\}$})=0$.

**More context:** This question arises since I'm looking for a "special" point $x^*\in E$ (say optimal in the sense of an objective $x^TA_0x$ with $A_0$ positive definite) and I want to make sure (or at least almost sure) that $x^*$ is regular.

**Questions:**

1. Do you think this approach is correct in order to make (almost) sure that the "optimal point" $x^*$ is regular?
2. Do you think such statement (that we can show that disturbing a little the matrices will make non regular points disappear) is true?
3. Do you have any idea how I can approach this problem to show such a statement?
4. Do you suggest any other approach?

Hopefully this is the right forum to ask this question. I'm not trying to find a full solution here of course. At this point, any suggestion is valuable for me.

P.S. I'm quite new to this site, so I'll try to choose the best tags. However, I would I appreciate if someone can add/remove tags if needed.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE**

This example appeals mostly to intuition, sorry if I'm not too rigorous in this part:
Consider $P_1=\text{diag}(1,1,2)$ and $P_2=\text{diag}(1,1,4)$. Clearly, the intersection of $E_1$ and $E_2$ is the unit circle on the "floor". This is, $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3: x = (x_1,x_2,0)^T, x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}$. Moreover, any point in $E$ have $P_1x=P_2x$. Hence, all points in $E$ are non regular. However, it should be easy to show (in this example) that disturbing a little $P_1,P_2$ will prevent the intersection to be full of non regular points, since $P_1,P_2$ were very carefully chosen (are a very degenerate case). They (non regular points) may not disappear completely, but my intuition is that they will lie in a set of measure zero, and therefore any $x\in E$ will be regular almost surely. **However, I don't have any intuition on what might happen in higher dimensions.**

Comment: Should we assume $m<n$?  And I guess we need a measure on $E$ to talk about the probability, so can we choose anything "reasonable"?

Comment: Sure. I missed that. Surely $m<n$. Thanks.

Comment: What more information do you think we should add (or what am I missing?) to define a meassure on E? Isnt the meassure that matters implied in the probability distribution of the matrices?

Comment: Just a remark: $P_i x$ is the gradient of $x^T P_i x -1$. So the condition of linear independence of the $P_ix$, at $x\in E$, is that the $E_i$ cut $E$ transversally.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your main goal but why does it not suffice to find, for each $\varepsilon >0$, a single pertubation leading to regular values only?

Comment: Let $P(\epsilon)$ the datum of the perturbed matrices and $E(\epsilon)$ the corresponding set. Is the condition that you require the following: For "generic" $\epsilon$ *every* point of $E(\epsilon)$ is regular; or did I misunderstand the quantifiers? In particular, you need a measure (or a notion of genericity) on the space of $\epsilon$'s, not on $E$, correct?

Comment: @Keba Because my idea was to perturb the matrices using "random noise". Hence, I would need almost any perturbation to lead to regular values. However, If you have ideas on what single perturbation could lead to regular values I would like to hear it. 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Qfwfq Yes, the notion of genericity is in $\epsilon$, not on $E$. And yes, ideally I would like to show that given generic $\varepsilon$, every point in $E(\epsilon)$ is regular. However, as I stated in the "more context" part, if one cannot show that the whole $E(\epsilon)$ is regular, it would be desirable to show at least that non-regular points are sufficiently rare, such to ensure that a certain optimum $x^*$ (in the sense of a cost $x^TA_0x$) is regular. Hope this motivation is clear. And again, any suggestion/advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375654/follow-up-show-that-these-vectors-are-linearly-independent-almost-surely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote $L_{\epsilon}(x):=\{(P_{1}+\epsilon_{1})x,\cdots,(P_{m}+\epsilon_{m})x\text{ linearly independant}\}$

First we have that for any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $$\mathbb{P}(L_{\epsilon}(x))=0.$$
Indeed if you only consider the $m$ first entries of these $m$ vectors you have get an $m\times m$ random matrix $M_{\epsilon}(x)$ with independant random entries. And then $\det(M_{\epsilon}(x))$ is a smooth random variable on \mathbb{R} so \mathbb{P}$(\det(M_{\epsilon}(x))=0)=0$. In fact we used that $$\{(\epsilon_{i})\in(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})^{m}:\det(M_{\epsilon}(x))=0\}$$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

The question now is what about $\mathbb{P}(L_\epsilon(x))$ but given the condition that $x\in E(\epsilon)$.

I will consider slitly different random matrices $$\tilde{\epsilon}_{i}=\epsilon_{i}+s_{i}I_{n}$$ where $s_{i}$ independent random variable in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ with continuous density and $I_{n}$ the identity matrix. The proof below works as well with just $\epsilon_{i}$ but it is a bit more complicate and I guess that this random law work as well for what you want. Then we can write $$x\in E_{i}(\epsilon)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:s_{i}=\frac{1}{\|x\|^{2}}(1-x^{T}(P+\epsilon_{i})x)\}$$

In a way we have decoupled the two events :${x\in E(\epsilon)}$ is a random event that depends on the variabl}e $s_{i}$, whereas $L_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a random event that depends on $\epsilon_i$.
We denote $\rho(s)$ the density for the $s$ variables, $\mu(\epsilon)$ the density for the $\epsilon$ variables and $\sigma_{E(\tilde{\epsilon})}$ the measure on the surface $E(\tilde{\epsilon})$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P}(\{\tilde{\epsilon}:\sigma_{E(\tilde{\epsilon})}(L_{\epsilon}(x))=0\})=0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow \int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{*}}\mu(\epsilon)d\epsilon\int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{m}}\rho(s)d^{m}s\int_{E(\epsilon)}1_{L_{\epsilon}(x)}d\sigma(x)=0
\\ & \Leftrightarrow \int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{*}}\mu(\epsilon)d\epsilon\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}1_{L_{\epsilon}(x)}\rho(\frac{1}{\|x\|^{2}}(1-x^{T}(P+\epsilon_{i})x))d^{n}x=0
\\ & \Leftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{*}}\mu(\epsilon)1_{L_{\epsilon}(x)}\rho(\frac{1}{\|x\|^{2}}(1-x^{T}(P+\epsilon_{i})x))d\epsilon d^{n}x=0
\end{align*}
And the last equality is satisfied because as we proved before for any $x$, $\{\epsilon:L_\epsilon(x)\}$ is Lebesgue measure $0$.

Conclusion, with probability 1 on $\tilde{\epsilon}$, The set of non regular point on $E(\tilde{\epsilon})$ is of measure 0.

Comment: This is awesome!  This already gives me a lot of useful info. Just to make sure I understand: we can't rule out non regular points completely right? 

As a side question (your answer is already great): Do you think we can conclude something about the probably of this "optimal point" $x^*$ I mentioned in my question? Since it is optimal in the sense of a cost $x^TA_0x$, one can show similarly (I guess) that the set of "optimal" points lie in a set of measure zero with probably one.

Can we show points $x^*$ are regular almost surely? (since we couldn't rule out nonregular ones completely)

Comment: Another comment, is it that $L_\epsilon(x)$ contain the indepedent vectors? did you mean dependent?

Comment: Sorry for so much questions, but once we change the matrices to be $\tilde{\epsilon_i}=\epsilon_i+s_iI_n$, shouldn't we focus on the linear dependency of the vectors $\{(P_i+\tilde{\epsilon}_i)x\}_{i=1}^m$ instead of $\{(P_i+\epsilon_i)x\}_{i=1}^m$ so that the set $L_\epsilon(x)$ is not truly decoupled from $s_i$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed it should be $L_\tilde{\epsilon}$ and we use that for all $s$, $\{\epsilon:\{(P_i+\epsilon_i+s_i)x \}\text{ linearly independant}\}$ is lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: Then, if $L_\tilde{\epsilon}$ contains regular points (with those vectors being linearly **independent**), thus the conclusion of $L_\tilde{\epsilon}$ being of Lebesgue measure 0, shouldn't correspond to the set of **regular** points on $E(\tilde{\epsilon})$ being of measure 0. Contrary to what is stated at the end of your answer?

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelB4, this answer helped me a lot. I awarded the bounty to you. However, I would appreciate if you could also address the comments I made here. Thanks anyway!

Comment: For the $x^TA_0 x$ I also thing the answer is yes almost surely. I can share another idea but it is far from being complete : If you can also add a another random modification $P_i \rightarrow UP_iU^T$ with $U=I+\epsilon''$ an small perturbation, (the same $U$ for all $P_i$). Then this should be equivalent to keep the $P_i$ and change $A_0 \rightarrow U^T A_0 U$. With this perturbation hopefully $x^*$ is random with a continuous law on $E$ and then is regular almost surely.